# Using Nim to connect to a SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, nim-lang

I have recently began to explore the Nim programming language and I was wondering how to connect to a SQLite database. After reading the relevant section of the manual, my confusion has not diminished. If someone would be kind enough to provide a simple example, I would appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: A Google search for `nim sqlite` gives me this: http://nim-lang.org/docs/db_sqlite.html

Answer (score 5):

Nim latest [source code](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/devel/lib/impure/db_sqlite.nim) provide a good example. Copy the example here:

```
import db_sqlite, math

let theDb = open("mytest.db", nil, nil, nil) # Open mytest.db

theDb.exec(sql"Drop table if exists myTestTbl")

# Create table
theDb.exec(sql("""create table myTestTbl (
    Id    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Name  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    i     INT(11),
    f     DECIMAL(18,10))"""))

# Insert
theDb.exec(sql"BEGIN")
for i in 1..1000:
 theDb.exec(sql"INSERT INTO myTestTbl (name,i,f) VALUES (?,?,?)",
       "Item#" & $i, i, sqrt(i.float))
theDb.exec(sql"COMMIT")

# Select
for x in theDb.fastRows(sql"select * from myTestTbl"):
 echo x

let id = theDb.tryInsertId(sql"INSERT INTO myTestTbl (name,i,f) VALUES (?,?,?)",
     "Item#1001", 1001, sqrt(1001.0))
echo "Inserted item: ", theDb.getValue(sql"SELECT name FROM myTestTbl WHERE id=?", id)

theDb.close()
```

Comment: i've played with this example as well, i had to download the prebuild sqlite library from their site and rename it to `sqlite3_32.dll` and placed it nearby my executable.